# Include error bars in BarChart in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm looking to indicate the standard error on the bars but it doesn't work as intended. The code I wrote gives me errors. I'll provide lower an example of how it should look. I've made some adjustments, it seemed to work but on app restart, the errors appear again.

Here's my code:

```
 standardError[val_] := StandardDeviation[val]/Sqrt[Length[val]]
 LRad = {7.43, 10.1, 6.07, 9.65};
 stdErr = standardError[LRad];

 LRad = Apply[Around, Transpose[{LRad, stdErr}], 1];
 BarChart[LRad, ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", 
 ChartStyle -> "Pastel", ImageSize -> 500,
 ChartLabels -> {"1", "2", "3", "4" }, LabelStyle -> {16, Bold},
 AxesLabel -> {"", "cm"}, BarSpacing -> 0.3, 
 LabelingFunction -> Bottom]
```

errors:
[image: errors]

how it should be:
the black lines indicate the amount of standard error for each bar. unfortunately they aren't dynamic and they display the wrong number.
[image: how it should be]

Answer (score 0):

Calculate `LRad` like so

```
LRad = Apply[Around, Transpose[{LRad, ConstantArray[stdErr, Length[LRad]]}], 1];
```

or shorter

```
LRad = Apply[Around, {#, stdErr} & /@ LRad, 1];
```